# WSACancelBlockingCall Exception with Amazon

Tags: amazon-s3

I have occasional exception when reading / storing objects with Amazon S3 from asp.net application.

Exception says: 
**Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall. A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall**

```
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

Any ideas about how I can locate what is reason  of this error?

here is my read function:

```
    public Image GetImage(string fullKey, out string errorMessage)
    {
        errorMessage = null;
        try
        {
            GetObjectResponse response = s3Client.GetObject(new GetObjectRequest()
            {
                BucketName = BucketName,
                Key = fullKey,
                Timeout = ImportTimeout
            });
            return Image.FromStream(response.ResponseStream);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorMessage = e.Message;
            Log.Current.WriteError(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

s3Client is initialised in constructor of this class:

```
s3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to aws documentation it is correct to wrap call to GetObject with using:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3_GetObject.htm

This eliminates all exceptions related to GetObject method